# $_FILES empty when uploading Magento package

Tags: php, magento, package, magento-1.9

I am trying to install a Magento package, but I get `No file was uploaded`

Its coming from this code because `$_FILES` is an empty array in `/downloader/Maged/Controller.php`

```
/**
 * Install uploaded package
 */
public function connectInstallPackageUploadAction()
{
    if (!$_FILES) {
        echo "No file was uploaded";
        return;
    }

    if(empty($_FILES['file'])) {
        echo "No file was uploaded";
        return;
    }

    $info =& $_FILES['file'];

    if(0 !== intval($info['error'])) {
        echo "File upload problem";
        return;
    }

    $target = $this->_mageDir . DS . "var/" . uniqid() . $info['name'];
    $res = move_uploaded_file($info['tmp_name'], $target);
    if(false === $res) {
        echo "Error moving uploaded file";
        return;
    }

    $this->model('connect', true)->installUploadedPackage($target);
    @unlink($target);
}
```

It might be worth noting that product uploads work fine.

The only log output I get is

> 2014-07-03T18:44:15+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Model/Observer.php on line 166

`exception.log` was empty

Comment: Make sure you are using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form.

Comment: The form is within the Magento Connect page, so I would hope it does! A quick look shows it does.

Comment: apache log? php log? floder permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your var folder in magento installation is fully writable. 777 permission. All folders and files.

Comment: Did that too. It would be a permissions error if that were the case? Rather than _FILES being empty?

Comment: Yes, when uploading is done in magento they are initially uploaded to one of the var folders and then used. If files have not been uploaded hence $_FILES empty. Check your log and system exception files it may be other issues as well.

Comment: Thats not it, var is completed 777'd and its the same

Comment: Can you add logs and exception files. We can get detailed info from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try uploading a small dummy file first to check if the error stays the same.

There is a file upload limit which might be reached.

File upload often fails due to `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size` being too small as mentioned in [Common Pitfalls](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php) section of the PHP documentation.

Comment: A tiny file (7KB) fails also. Image files work fine from within Magento's usual admin area.

Answer (score 1):

Use firebug in firefox to check if your form does has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: It does. See comments on the original question.

Comment: Is the action of your form directs to `connectInstallPackageUpload`?

Comment: Yes, here is the full form element `<form action="/downloader/index.php?A=connectInstallPackageUpload" method="post" target="connect_iframe" onsubmit="onSubmit(this)" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: try to print values in `indexAction()`, use condition like if(isset($_FILES)){print_r($_FILES);exit;} at the start of the `indexAction()`

Answer (score 1):

Check the user group it was created with,

To explain, recently I had some file saving issues.  Turned out I had created the folder using the Root user for the server, and the CPanel user ( the one php was running under ) didn't have permission to write in folders owned by the Root account, even when setting the permissions to 777.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

First check if your installation is configured properly 
see@http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

Also, *if* you upload with PUT/xhr the file is on the input stream

`$in = fopen('php://input','r');`

see@http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php and https://stackoverflow.com/a/11771857/2645347,

this would explain the **empty $FILES array**, in case all else is ok and the upload works via xhr/PUT.

Answer (score 1):

$_FILES is an associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method. All uploaded files are stored in $HTTP_POST_FILES contains the same initial information, but is not a superglobal. So, ... be sure that method is POST

Always check that your form contains correct enctype:

```
<form ... enctype="multipart/form-data"> ... </form>
```

Sometimes happens that when someone upload multiples file, $_FILES return empty. This could happen when I select files that exceed some size. The problem can be in the POST_MAX_SIZE configuration.

Comment: This isn't it, please read other comments and answers before posting

Answer (score 1):

On

```
app/code/core/mage/captcha/model/observer.php
```

change

```
public function checkUserLoginBackend($observer)
{
$formId = 'backend_login';
        $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
        $loginParams = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        $login = array_key_exists('username', $loginParams) ? $loginParams['username'] : null;
        if ($captchaModel->isRequired($login)) {
            if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString(Mage::app()->getRequest(), $formId))) {
                $captchaModel->logAttempt($login);
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
            }
        }
        $captchaModel->logAttempt($login);
        return $this;
    }
```

to

```
public function checkUserLoginBackend($observer)
{
    $formId = 'backend_login';
    $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);

    $login = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('username');
    if ($captchaModel->isRequired($login)) {
        if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString(Mage::app()->getRequest(), $formId))) {
            $captchaModel->logAttempt($login);
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
        }


    }
    $captchaModel->logAttempt($login);
    return $this;
}
```

Your issue is:
"Captcha Observer throws an error if login in RSS feed" issue #208

or if you wish you could only replace the variable $login to be like this:

```
$login = array_key_exists('username', array($loginParams)) ? $loginParams['username'] : null;
```

Comment: Thats a good shout, but its not worked. If I put a die statement in that function it does die. So it is running your code, its just not fixed it.

Comment: and what happen if you put print_r($_FILES); die(); ?

Comment: I get a blank array. I have now upgraded to Magento 1.9 and get the same issue.

Comment: That's weird, what kind of error_reporting do you have activated? if not already can you change to E_ALL and run your code again, so if there is a notice of an empty variable, we may have more chances to debug.

Comment: Where is best to add this within Magento. I know how to do it, but just unsure when it comes to Magento?

Comment: you should have a public folder that has only 1 php file called index, as first line put it, it works for me on zf2

Comment: lol. Thats what I tried, no errors. Just `No file was uploaded`.

Comment: can you try with another magento package? just to make sure that the problem is not package.

Comment: I just tried this using the key, http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/riskified-fraud-prevention.html, it just bombs. No errors. Nothing.

Comment: so, the problem was the package??

Comment: No, that package doesn't do anything at all when using the key to install. It just bombs.

Answer (score -1):

You may try out below points.
Use Magento Varien File Uploaded Classes to Upload the files.

[Magento File Uploader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329142/using-move-uploaded-file-in-magento-controller)

1) Check `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form.

2) Use Magento Form Key in your form.

3) Use Varien file uploader to upload your files using below links answers.